# Can one quantize Chern-Simons theory in the covariant phase space formalism?

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, covariance, quantization, chern-simons-theory

The covariant phase space, which coincides with the space of solutions to the equations of motion, gives a notion of phase space which does not rely on a decomposition of spacetime of the form $M=\Sigma\times\mathbb{R}$. One could then consider quantizations of this phase space, which should lead to a global notion for the Hilbert space. This is in contrast to the results most commonly obtained when using a decomposition $M=\Sigma\times\mathbb{R}$ and a phase space consisting on initial conditions on $\Sigma$, where the Hilbert space is commonly associated to $\Sigma$. This is also in contrast with the path integral intuition of assigning the Hilbert space to a codimension 1 submanifold corresponding to the possible boundary conditions on it. Finally, this notion of quantization doesn't even rely on the hyperbolic or elliptic nature of the equations of motion. I was wondering if this idea had been successfully implemented in a theory defined on a non-trivial $M$.

A particular example of this would be for example Chern-Simons theory. Its covariant phase space would consist of the connections with vanishing curvature and it has a symplectic form
$$\omega=\int_{\Sigma}\text{d}A\wedge\text{d}A,$$
with $\Sigma$ any 2D submanifold in $M$. Does quantization of this structure lead to a "covariant" Hilbert space?